# Performing a grep on "NAK" character

Tags: linux, grep

I am trying to perform a grep on a file that contains "NAK" characters (http://www.theasciicode.com.ar/ascii-control-characters/nak-negative-acknowledge-ascii-code-21.html).

When I open the file with vi, this NAK character is displayed as "^U". I tried `grep ^U myfile.csv` but it does not work.

Do you know how I could identify this character to match it on the grep command?

Comment: Do you mean `grep -a $'\x15' someFile` ?

Comment: yes but this representation is for java or Python (http://condor.depaul.edu/sjost/lsp121/documents/ascii-npr.htm) isn't it?

Comment: It's for the `bash` shell.

Comment: just key in it as Ctrl-V and follow that with Ctrl-U  (Ctrl means to press the control key, and while pressing, key in the V or U keys)  Ctrl-V is a prefix for the shell to accept the next char as literal, and immediately press the second one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's make a little file with the first 128 ASCII codes in it for demonstration:

```
perl -e 'for($i=0;$i<128;$i++){printf("%c",$i)}' > someFile
```

And look at it in hex:

```
xxd someFile

00000000: 0001 0203 0405 0607 0809 0a0b 0c0d 0e0f  ................
00000010: 1011 1213 1415 1617 1819 1a1b 1c1d 1e1f  ................
00000020: 2021 2223 2425 2627 2829 2a2b 2c2d 2e2f   !"#$%&'()*+,-./
00000030: 3031 3233 3435 3637 3839 3a3b 3c3d 3e3f  0123456789:;<=>?
00000040: 4041 4243 4445 4647 4849 4a4b 4c4d 4e4f  @ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO
00000050: 5051 5253 5455 5657 5859 5a5b 5c5d 5e5f  PQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_
00000060: 6061 6263 6465 6667 6869 6a6b 6c6d 6e6f  `abcdefghijklmno
00000070: 7071 7273 7475 7677 7879 7a7b 7c7d 7e7f  pqrstuvwxyz{|}~.
```

Now, if you want to find the NAK, (hex 15), the easiest way to see it in context, is to regroup the hex into single bytes (`-g1`) and then look for `15` with a word boundary at the start and end, so that you only find the `15` in the hex part and not in the offset at the start of each line and not in the ASCII part at the end of each line:

```
xxd -g1 a | grep "\b15\b"
```

00000010: 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 1a 1b 1c 1d 1e 1f  ................

And now you can see it and the characters surrounding it. To make that a little clearer, let's imagine you were looking for `A` which is hex 41:

```
xxd -g1 a | grep "\b41\b"
00000040: 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 4a 4b 4c 4d 4e 4f  @ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO
```

You can now see the `41` at the third field, and also see the letters surrounding the `A` in the ASCII part at the end of the line (right side).

---

The other method that will find the `NAK` but may output a mess of control characters is as I said in the comments:

```
grep -a $'\x15' someFile
```

---

Another "trick" when searching for control characters is to convert them to some other character and then look for that. So, choose something that doesn't occur much in your files, maybe a `|` or a `#`, convert your NAKs to that, and then search for that.

As a concrete example, let's convert your troublesome NAKs into pipe symbols `|` and then search:

```
tr '\015' '|' < YourFile | grep -a '|'
```

Or, say you have ACKs and NAKs in your file, convert them to `<` and `>` and search for either:

```
tr '\006\015' '<>' < YourFile | grep -Ea '<|>'
```

Answer (score 1):

> I tried `grep ^U myfile.csv` but it does not work.

To grep the Control-U character, you must not type in the graphical representation <kbd>^</kbd><kbd>U</kbd> as the pattern; type a literal Control-U instead. To do this, you have to precede it with the *quoted-insert* special key Control-V, i. e. type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>U</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

```
#od -c can identify those non-printable character and represent them in octal

echo "$line"| od -c;
```

Comment: And how octal (or hex or decimal) representation can be used with grep command?